# Selenium Address Bar

Tags: selenium

Good morning

I am using selenium and I have come up against a bit of a wall.

I am attempting to navigate to another page, by typing in the address bar, however I cant seem to do this when using selenium.

Is this possible?

I am not able to simply put a link on the page that goes to this page.

Cheers Cameron

Answer (score 3):

Short answer: Try the "open" command.

Long answer: Selenium doesn't support "typing in the address bar". It can only control what is *IN* the page canvas, or more specifically, it can only do what JavaScript can do. In other words, it can change the location, but not by actually typing something in to the address bar. The open command uses JavaScript to change the page's location.

Answer (score 0):

The address bar is where you put the base url,

and to use the open the url you need to use the selenium open command,

EX:

Base URL: google.com

command1#

command = open
target = /